# What forces act on a car during cornering? (Forward inertia and centripetal force?)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force, inertia

I was testing the physics of an old car racing game on a completely flat, circular course.  The game does not simulate downforce or lift, so we can imagine the test was conducted inside a vacuum:

Radius - Average Speed - Lateral G:

- 50 metres = 50.5944mph = 1.043G
- 110 metres = 75.1437mph = 1.046G
- 200 metres = 101.048mph = 1.047G

The car's weight is 500kg and the game's code bases all physics calculations around the standard gravitational constant, so we can assume this test happened on Earth.

1. Physics wise, is this possible that they are able to corner at the same lateral G regardless of corner radius?
2. If not, what other forces would be expected in real life?
3. Based on the results of the 50m radius test, is it possible to calculate the expected cornering forces for 110m and 200m radius corners?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum speed with which the car can take a corner is determined by the radius of the corner and the coefficient of friction $\mu$ between the car's tyres and the road. The centripetal force required to go round a corner of radius $r$ at speed $v$ is

$$F = \frac {mv^2}{r}$$

The maximum frictional force available is $\mu mg$, so we must have

$$\frac {mv^2}{r} <= \mu mg \\ \Rightarrow v^2 <= \mu g r$$

The maximum lateral acceleration of the car is $\mu g$. Since typical values of $\mu$ are usually less than 1, it is impossible to go round a corner with a lateral acceleration as high as 1 G without [downforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downforce). If downforce is present, this increases the apparent weight of the car and hence increases the maximum available friction and the maximum cornering speed for a given radius of corner. Formula 1 cars, for example, depend on downforce to be able to corner at high speed - they can produce downforces up to three times the weight of the car.

Answer (score 0):

> Physics wise, is this possible that they are able to corner at the same lateral G regardless of corner radius?

Yes, assuming unlimited friction force. The friction force is the one that provides the centripetal force. If the friction force isn't large enough, then the car cannot corner; it will turn but not by enough. With unlimited friction, this isn't an issue.

> Based on the results of the 50m radius test, is it possible to calculate the expected cornering forces for 110m and 200m radius corners?

Yes. The equation for centripetal force is $F = mv^2/r$. If you know the centripetal force for 50m radius, you can calculate it for 110m and 200m. In your case you only have the radius and the speed, which is not enough to calculate the force, only enough to calculate the acceleration.

Comment: In reality there is not unlimited friction. If a car, for example, cornered with the following forces instead, would friction be the limiting factor or something else? :

50m radius - 1.3G // 100m radius - 1.2G // 200m radius - 1.1G

Comment: @user1708538 I don't know. It would depend on the mass of the car, the make of its tyres, and the make of the road. Given the coefficient of friction between the car and the road I can calculate it, but I don't know what the coefficient of friction is for a typical car and a typical road.

Comment: Apparently asphalt has a friction coefficient of 0.7-0.85 approximately.

Comment: @user1708538 still need the mass of the car.

Comment: 500kg (stated in the original post lol)

Comment: @user1708538 then the maximum friction force is 4000N while the centripetal force (50m case) is 64000N; the car cannot make the corner.

Comment: Right, I think I understand. So, the only way to match these up is to increase the mu coefficient, right?

Comment: @user1708538 or have downforce, see gandalf61's answer.